# How to override the default jest-junit output file name - junit.xml

Tags: typescript, jest-junit

I am running a test using jest-junit and I want to change the default name of the output file which is `junit.xml`. I don't want to specify the outputname in the package.json or jest.config but instead I want to specify it in the ci something like

`npx jest --ci --testResultsProcessor="jest-junit" --outputName="test.xml"`

But this is still giving the output file as junit.xml. Is there something missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I achieved that by passing the file name to the environment variable JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME.

ref- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-junit

Comment: consider answer your own question